# Magento Custom Grid Redirect Error (On Join Attributes ONLY)

Tags: layout, adminhtml, grid, ajax, grid-serlization

**To clarify, this is ONLY on join attributes**

My layout handles are **correctly** setup, I can filter the inherited columns correctly.

```
$collection->getSelect()->join(
        array('entity_int_status' => 'catalog_product_entity_int'),
        'entity_int_status.attribute_id = 80 AND entity_int_status.entity_id = main_table.product_id',
        array('status' => 'entity_int_status.value')
);
```

That's how I've joined the `status` value from `catalog_product_entity_int` in my Grid. If I try filter by this column, Magento:

1. On first attempt redirects to the dashboard, and if I then try view the page again
2. Throws an error report, reading that the column cannot be found

I need to log out & back in again to get the page to load again (i.e forget the filters). Why are the attributes which are joined not able to be filtered?

**Edit 1**: Please note that this is only for filter, not sort.

Comment: To debug try setting `$this->setSaveParametersInSession(false);` (may stop you from have to re-login). Can you add the `addColumn` code for status? Also try add the table prefix for `status`. Also try debug the sql `Mage::log($collection->getSelect())`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if suggest left joint:
fist get status attribute

**step1:**

```
$status = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product')->getAttribute('status');
```

**step2:**

```
$collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(
    array('product' => $status->getBackend()->getTable()),
    'product.entity_id = main_table.product_id
    AND product.attribute_id = '.(int) $status->getAttributeId().'',
    array('status_name'=>'value')
    );
```

add grid colums:

```
 $this->addColumn('status_name', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('yourhelper')->__('Status'),
        'align' =>'left',
        'index' => 'status_name',
        'filter_index' =>'product.value'
      ));
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the code as following:

```
$collection->getSelect()->join('catalog_product_entity_int',
        'catalog_product_entity_int.attribute_id = 80 AND catalog_product_entity_int.entity_id = main_table.product_id',
        array('status' => 'catalog_product_entity_int.value')
);
```

Hope it will work.

Comment: Doesn't make a difference. Same issue persists.

Comment: are you using the code before `$this->setCollection($collection);
return parent::_prepareCollection();`

Comment: Accepted Amit Bera's answer, this got me sorted out. And yes, to answer your question, I was declaring the code before those calls.