# Magento Custom Grid Left Join ID Conflict with Custom Table

Tags: mysql, grid

I've got the following left join in my `_prepareCollection();` method:

```
$collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(
        array('views_index' => "my_views_table"),
        'views_index.entity_id = main_table.entity_id',
        array('views'=>'count')
);
```

And then in my `_prepareColumns()` method I have:

```
$this->addColumn('views',
        array(
            'header'=> $this->__('Views'),
            'index' => 'views',
            'width' => '5%',
            'filter_index'  => 'views_index.count'
        )
);
```

When I load this page though, I get an error:

> Item (Namespace_Module_Model_Mymodel) with the same
>   id "{ID}" already exist

How is this conflict occurring?

Some background: [Magento Custom Grid Redirect Error (On Join Attributes ONLY)](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/33943/magento-custom-grid-redirect-error-on-join-attributes-only)

Would appreciate any help

**Edit 1** The `my_views_table` consists of 3 columns, namely:

1. id (primary key)
2. entity_id
3. count

Answer (score 1):

You are joining one table to another with 1-N relationship.

It means for one row from the table A you get N rows from the table B

At the same time you fetch values to the magento collection, that use unique row ID
and it throws the error.

Probably you need to group values, so if it is page views you can group by page_id
and calculate count with aggregate function.

Note, that with the `group by` statement in the original SQL query you need custom approach for the pager as the default wont work. So sometimes it easier (but not faster or better) to use subqueries.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Why does this only happen when using my custom table? If I use the exact same join on an EAV table, there is no such problem.

Comment: It may depend on the number of records.  If table B contains only 1 corresponding record for table A, you will see no error.  But when you add the second record in the table B the result will contain 2 rows and you'll see the error.

Comment: Please accept the answer or edit the question with the data samples so me or someone else can get better advice / exact code fix.

Comment: I've updated my question.

Comment: So as you can see for one `id` (primary key) you have multiple `entity_id`.  Add the groupby to the select object. `$collection->getSelect()->group('id');`